# How do i synchronously get the result of a Promise

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a function that goes to the database and returns array of objects like so:

```
function findAlbumImages(){
   remote.findAlbum.then(
       res =>{

       })    
}
```

but I want to call this from another function and assign that res to array collection like so:

```
let newArray = findAlbumImages();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can return promise from findAlbumImages(). use then function on another function.

Comment: Sorry in advance, I know this isn't the right place. Ivaylo, you deleted one of your questions before I could answer. Didn't want to waste the effort, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/SydLambert/hnkL392x/2/

Comment: @ivaylo No problem, happy to help :) Can you please post the link to it, it's not showing up.

Comment: @SydLambert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046647/bouncing-draggable-ball

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can, by using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which is the closest you can
get to your desired syntax:

```
function findAlbumImages() {
  return remote.findAlbum()
}

(async () => {
  let newArray = await findAlbumImages()

  console.log(newArray)
})()
```

Comment: Hello so this is what it returns {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're doing `await findAlbumImages()` just like I have in my example.

Comment: Yes, thank you can you please gvie me an idea to what it returns without the await, is this a function that it returns?

Comment: I guess i found something about it, thanks anyway.